# Python pandas json_normalize joining with dataframe field

Tags: python, json, pandas, optimization, normalize

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, '{"issues": [{"issue_name": "fixed.issue.cpeUnreachable", "issue_id": "52446*", "actions": [], "issueFixed": "true"}, {"issue_name": "fixed.issue.internet.cgnat.statusActive", "issueFixed": "false", "issue_id": "8834*4", "actions": [            {"action_name": "cableCheck", "success": "false"},             {"action_name": "otherCheck", "success": "true"}]}, {"issue_name": "fixed.issue.rf.ds.quality", "issue_id": "3642*", "actions": [            {"action_name": "akcija 1", "success": "false"},             {"action_name": "akcija 2", "success": "false"},             {"action_name": "akcija 3", "success": "false"},             {"action_name": "akcija 4", "success": "false"},             {"action_name": "akcija 5", "success": "false"}], "issueFixed": "true"}, {"issue_name": "fixed.issue.rf.us.quality", "issueFixed": "false", "issue_id": "8834*3", "actions": []},    {"issue_name" : "rebootBeforeTicket",        "actions" : [{"action_name": "rebootCpeDevice", "success" : "false"},            {"action_name": "rebootStbDevice", "success" : "true"}]} ]}'],
    [2, '{"issues": [{"issue_name": "fixed.issue.cpeUnreachable", "issue_id": "52446*", "actions": [], "issueFixed": "true"}, {"issue_name": "fixed.issue.internet.cgnat.statusActive", "issueFixed": "false", "issue_id": "8834*4", "actions": [            {"action_name": "cableCheck", "success": "false"},             {"action_name": "otherCheck", "success": "true"}]}, {"issue_name": "fixed.issue.rf.ds.quality", "issue_id": "3642*", "actions": [            {"action_name": "akcija 1", "success": "false"},             {"action_name": "akcija 2", "success": "false"},             {"action_name": "akcija 3", "success": "false"},             {"action_name": "akcija 4", "success": "false"},             {"action_name": "akcija 5", "success": "false"}], "issueFixed": "true"}, {"issue_name": "fixed.issue.rf.us.quality", "issueFixed": "false", "issue_id": "8834*3", "actions": []},    {"issue_name" : "rebootBeforeTicket",        "actions" : [{"action_name": "rebootCpeDevice", "success" : "false"},            {"action_name": "rebootStbDevice", "success" : "true"}]} ]}']], 
    columns=['session_id', 'json_text'])
df
```

[image]

I would like to transform this dataframe to:

[image]

So far I have tried the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    json_contents = json.loads(row.stat_dimen_value)
    df_json = json_normalize(json_contents['issues'], record_path=['actions'], meta=['issue_id', 'issue_name', 'issueFixed'], errors='ignore')
    df_json.insert(0, 'session_id', row.session_id)
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, df_json])


df1 = df1[['session_id', 'issue_id', 'issue_name', 'issueFixed', 'action_name', 'success']]
```

It works, but I am not satisfied with the for loop.
I had to join newly crated df_json (from df.json_text field) dataframe with df.session_id field. As I couldn't find another way, I used the for loop.

Is there a better way to join df_json with its df.session_id (maybe som other df fields as well) field(s) without using for loop?

Regards.

EDIT 1, solution with json inject:

```
json_ser = df.apply(lambda row: json.loads(row.stat_dimen_value[:1] + f'"session_id":{row.session_id}, ' + row.stat_dimen_value[1:]), axis=1)
json_ser.head()


df1 = json_normalize(json_ser, \
    record_path=['issues', 'actions'], \
    meta=['session_id', ['issues', 'issue_id'], ['issues', 'issue_name'], ['issues', 'issueFixed']], \
    sep='_', \
    errors='ignore') \
    .rename(columns={'issues_issue_id' : 'issue_id', 'issues_issue_name' : 'issue_name', 'issues_issueFixed' : 'issueFixed'}) \
    [['session_id', 'issue_id', 'issue_name', 'issueFixed', 'action_name', 'success']]
```

apply injects field session_id into json, and than json_normalize has all information for parsing.

I have created test performance dataframe with 2048 rows. On my laptop, for loop took 8.92 seconds, while apply + json_normalize took 387 + 167 ms.
Looks like injecting json is much faster.

Comment: have you tried using [pd.read_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) ?

Comment: It is no matter which function for reading json I will use. The problem is in combining newly created dataframe from json with fields from original dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Best I could do is this - still uses looping but will definitely save you some time

```
def joiner(x):
    a = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(json.loads(x[1])['issues'], record_path=['actions'], 
        meta=['issue_id','issue_name','issueFixed'],errors='ignore'))
    return pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Session':[x[0]] * a.shape[0]}), a], axis=1)

pd.concat([joiner(x[1] )for x in df.iterrows()])
```

Comment: Your idea is a little bit better than mine, but it is still a for loop. I came to an idea to inject needed information to json field. I will update original question with code sample.